# How do I get parameters from bind() in c?

Tags: c, windows, listener, bind

I'm writing a program in `C` (on windows 32bit) that listening on a specific port.  (using this [guide](http://www.tenouk.com/Winsock/Winsock2example2.html))

The client connect in that way: "http://127.0.0.1:port/?param1=a&param2=b..."

I (as a server) want to get all of the parameters he entered.

How can i do that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Also, if you are connecting to the server with a web-browser, you should read the [HTTP specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). But even before that I suggest you try something simpler, like just accepting connections, accepting and communicate with multiple connections, receiving and sending.

Comment: [Google for simple http web server c](https://www.google.com/search?q=simple+http+web+server+c). You will find plenty of sample codes.

Comment: Thanx, I'll check for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bind()` function does not receive the parameters, or for that matter anything the client is specifying regarding your communication; it merely binds to the port. Once a port is bound to and an active connection eventually gets established, your application protocol (HTTP presumably, in your case) takes over in the sense of deciding what data to `write()` (or other higher level functions) to the port.

With that in mind, your question has actually nothing at all to do with sockets in any way. Rather, it has to do with understanding the application protocol you're using. I would suggest you either Google how to use the HTTP protocol, review one of the myriad open source HTTP libraries available, or for theat matter just printf() the input you receive from your client.